# Error single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql

This query returns collection of data. but I only need customer list.

`select * from customer where cust_acnt_nbr = (select cust_acnt_nbr from Asset where dstrct_id = (select dstrct_id from dstrct where dstrct_nm = 'ATLANTA'))`

please help me to get customer list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `in` instead of `=` if a subquery can return multiple rows:

```
select * from customer where cust_acnt_nbr IN
    (select cust_acnt_nbr from Asset where dstrct_id IN
        (select dstrct_id from dstrct where dstrct_nm = 'ATLANTA'))
```

Comment: if I convert it to HQL, is this correct ? `from customer where cust_acnt_nbr in (select cust_acnt_nbr from Asset where dstrct_id in (select dstrct_id from dstrct where dstrct_nm = 'ATLANTA'))`

Answer (score 1):

I try to avoid subqueries as they can have poor performance and make it unclear what you're trying to achieve.  You can usually convert it to a series of simple joins which are easier to read.

```
select c.* 
from customer c
inner join Asset a on c.cust_acnt_nbr = a.cust_acnt_nbr 
inner join dstrct d on d.dstrct_id =a.dstrct_id 
where dstrct_nm = 'ATLANTA'
```